# MySQL find pairs in table

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this

```
+----+----+----+----+
| id | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  a |  x | 13 |
|  2 |  b |  z | 27 |
|  3 |  c |  y | 24 |
|  4 |  a |  y | 11 |
|  5 |  a |  x | 19 |
|  6 |  b |  y | 22 |
|  7 |  b |  z | 20 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

I need to find all rows with a duplicate `(c1, c2)` value pair.

How would I do that?

Comment: Can you shows us have did you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using WHERE:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c1, t2.c2
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1 
AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
AND t1.id != t2.id
```

Using INNER JOIN

```
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t2.c1, t2.c2
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
ON t1.c1 = t2.c1 
AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
AND t1.id != t2.id
```

Explanation:

t1 and t2 refer to the same table.
Search in the table t1 records that have the same c1 and c2 but different ID in t2.

Comment: Works as well. Probably a very elegant method, but harder for me to comprehend. My bad :-)

Comment: I may add that this is also the faster method compared to the one suggested by juergen d, which takes more than 10 times as long.

Comment: Exactly, this one is more efficient because it does contain a `count()` nor nested queries.

Comment: better if you rewrited it with inner join

Comment: Shouldn't you have "FROM t1 INNER JOIN t1 AS t2" aliasing for the self-JOIN in order to make the rest of the example work?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where id not in
(
  select min(id)
  from your_table
  group by c1, c2
  having count(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: Works! I forgot that you can group over two columns. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use join also

```
select t.* from t join (
select * from t group by c1,c2 having count(*) >1
) t1 using(c1,c2)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/899d6/1)